# C++ Lambda capture of const T& and T&& parameters by value

Tags: c++, c++20

I'm struggling with how to reason about lambda captures of reference variables, and how to capture reference variables by value efficiently. I've been through the C++20 standards docs; but the source material is dense and impenetrable.

The goal: efficiently produce *by-value* captures of `const T&` and `T&&` parameters.

---

The answer (with more details, if you will only re-open):

Argument: const T&value, capture: [this,value]: Two copy constructor calls.

Argument: T&&value, capture: [this,value]: One copy constructor, one move constructor call.

Argument: T&&value, capture: [this, valueCopy = std::move(value)]: Two move constructors.

In each case, two constructors and one destructor are called while constructing the lambda; and one destructor gets called while destroying the lambda.

*Surprisingly*, the most efficient way to capture is with an explicit capture!

Tested with GNU G++ 10.2.

---

**Edit:** The remainder of this post arises from a misconception triggered by an oddity in the decltype of captured variables. (see comments). I should probably have deleted the answer, and skulked off in shame; but after hooking up a test harness and counting the operations involved, I discovered a surprise. So rather than deleting, I'm going to answer the question (which is a good one), and ask you to ignore the rest of the post.]

---

*BEYOND THIS POINT LIES ONLY FOOLISHNESS AND DELUSION. READ NO FURTHER*

Values captured by value are always captured by value.

---

```
CoTask<> Push(const T&value) {
     co_await coConditionVariable.Wait([value] () {
          // called OUTSIDE of Push, often on another thread... 
          if (list.size() == MAX_QUEUE_SIZE) return false; // suspend execution.
          list.push_back(value); // <-- DANGLING REFERENCE! 
          return true; // allow the coroutine to resume.

     });
}
```

(In the concrete manifestation, the lambda is called (under protection of a std::mutex) on the thread that is Take-ing values, so the dangling reference is fatal).

VS code analysis says the type of `value` inside the lambda is `const T&`, which means that `value` is a dangling reference that will be used outside its lifetime. It appears that a 'by value capture of a reference' is a reference. :-/

So the question is, how to efficiently capture by value?, given that copies and moves of `T` are potentially quite expensive. The goal is to do this with a single constructor/move-constructor, without an aditional copy.

I came up with the following solution (C++14, with possible C++20 amendments). It works, but it is not clear to me whether the this will generate a copy constructor call followed by an additional copy operation, or whether return elision applies here too.

```
CoTask<> Push(const T&value) {
     co_await coCondtionVariable.Wait([value_ = T(value)] () {
          ... use value_, now definitely not dangling ...
          list.push_back(std::move(value));
     });
}
```

While `[value_ = T(value)]`  produces `value_`, with a non-reference type, does it also do an additional copy or move as well during the capture?

And the same question for `T&&`...

```
CoTask<> Push(T&&value) {
     co_await coCondtionVariable.Wait([value_ = std::move(value)] () {
          ... use value_ ...
          list.push_back(std::move(value_));
          ... 
     });
}
```

Or should it be `[value_ = T(std::move(value))]`? (It should, I think). But is that one move, or two?

Truthfully, I should probably cook up a test program with a type that has all possible move/copy assignments and constructors, to see what happens. But I'd still be stuck with having to guess how this stuff behaves. Any insights, preferably without having to reason too much about `ClosureType::operator ret(*)(params)()` and friends, would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: You can't copy a reference so what you have inside your lambda is a copy of `value`. Nothing dangling there.

Comment: `[value]` or `[value = /* */]` will *copy* `value` into the lambda, so I guess there is no dangling reference here?

Comment: What exactly is the code analysis saying? `[value]` captures by-copy. However it is correct that `decltype(value)` is `const T&` inside the lambda, since that form of `decltype` will not refer to the closure member.

Comment: @user17732522 : ok! very strange glitch.    For [this, value], the decltype(value) within the lambda *is by-reference!, but the capture is definitely by value. For [this,valueCopy=value], decltype(valueCopy) is NOT a reference (and it of course a copy. I wrote the test code to check. Going to have to look for my double-delete somewhere else. :-(

Comment: @RobinDavies Yes, that is the specified behavior. If your question really is about why `decltype` has this behavior, I think you should adjust your question accordingly. (Although I guess there are duplicates.)

Comment: I think I should probably delete my question. :-P (a shame because the actual test harness results had an interesting surprise).

Comment: Creating a lambda closure object should not involve two constructors for the same captured variable. Perhaps your test is actually copying the closure object right after it's created?